# Continuous mapping theorem with density convergence

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Let us consider a bivariate random variable $X\in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $pdf$ $f$. Also let, based on a sample of size $n$, let the the estimator of the density be $f_n(x)$ at $x\in \mathbb{R^2}$ and we know that $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$, a.s uniformly.

Now, we consider a continuous map $\phi:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow[0,1]$.

Then how to show $\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}\phi(x)f_n(x)dx\rightarrow\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}\phi(x)f(x)dx$, a.s.?

I am trying to prove this using DCT, but the problems are: How to extend the DCT to the multivariate case and what could be the dominated function (since $f$ could be unbounded function)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You definitely need to assume stronger conditions. It seems that you need uniform convergence of $f_n$...

Comment: @d.k.o. I can assume uniform convergence. I edited the question. Still I have those doubts.

Comment: If the integrands converge uniformly, you can swap the integral sign with the limit sign.

Comment: @user251257. Ohhh I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, I meant a.s. uniform convergence. If, in addition, you assume that the support of $f$ is compact or $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\phi(x)dx<\infty$ then the result follows because

$$\left|\int\phi(x)(f_n(x)-f(x))dx \right|\le \sup_x|f_n(x)-f(x)|\int\phi(x)dx\xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$$

Comment: a.s. uniformly, you meant $\Pr[ \|f_n - f\|_\infty \to 0 ] = 1$ right?

Comment: @user251257...Yes

Comment: @user23510: Then it is still true, $\| \phi f_n - \phi f \|_\infty \le \| \phi \|_\infty \| f_n - \phi f \|_\infty \le \| f_n - \phi f \|_\infty \to 0$ a.s. Thus, on a set of probability 1 we may interchange limit with integral.